# Can I pass parameters to a function debounced with _.lodash?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have been trying to use _lodash.debounce() and i have it working. However i am 
not sure if it's working the best way it could be. I looked at the example on the lodash web site and they seem to be just simple examples that don't pass around parameters. Here's what i have:

```
$scope.parsePid = _.debounce(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        var pid = $scope.option.sPidRange;
        if (pid == null || pid === "") {
            $scope.pidLower = null;
            $scope.pidUpper = null;
        }
        else if (pid.indexOf("-") > 0) {
            pid = pid.split("-");
            $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid[0]);
            $scope.pidUpper = parseInt(pid[1]);
        }
        else {
            $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid);
            $scope.pidUpper = null;
        }
    });
}, 1500);
```

The above code returns a function `$scope.parsePid` that's debounced. Notice that on the 4th
line i get the value of `$scope.option.SPidRange` and use that in the function. I really want to somehow pass in this parameter rather than get it this way.

I call the function like this:

```
$scope.$watch("option.sPidRange", function (pid) {
    if (pid !== null) {
        $scope.parsePid();
    }
});
```

Here the value pid should be equal to `$scope.parsePid`

I would like to pass this value of pid into the debounced function but i am not sure
how to do this. I tried a few different things but the debounce function gives an 
error.

Is it possible to pass parameters into the debounced `function $scope.parsePid()` ?

Comment: What are the $ signs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### UPDATE

You should pass an argument into the function: `_.debounce(function (pid) {`

[An example with debounce](http://plnkr.co/edit/bp51xt1FJP1WGdMSG2D7?p=preview)

```
$scope.parsePid = _.debounce(function(pid){
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    if (pid === null || pid === "") {
      $scope.pidLower = null;
      $scope.pidUpper = null;
    } else if (pid.indexOf("-") > 0) {
      pid = pid.split("-");
      $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid[0],10);
      $scope.pidUpper = parseInt(pid[1],10);      
    } else {
      $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid,10);
      $scope.pidUpper = null;
    }      
  });
},1500);
```

#### I would use the built-in $timeout

[An example with $timeout](http://plnkr.co/edit/YkXRbhKFoO6cNf532oJE?p=preview)

```
var promise;

$scope.parsePid = function(pid){
  $timeout.cancel(promise);
  promise = $timeout(function(){     
    if (pid === null || pid === "") {
      $scope.pidLower = null;
      $scope.pidUpper = null;
    } else if (pid.indexOf("-") > 0) {
      pid = pid.split("-");
      $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid[0],10);
      $scope.pidUpper = parseInt(pid[1],10);      
    } else {
      $scope.pidLower = parseInt(pid,10);
      $scope.pidUpper = null;
    }
  },1500);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a difference between me wrapping the if {} inside $scope.$apply() and doing it with $scope.$apply() at the end?

Comment: Actually **you should wrap it** inside $scope.$apply(function(){}).  
I just made it so it will look more clear. read this: [$scope.$apply() vs $scope.$apply(fn)](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html#scopeapply_vs_scopeapplyfn)

Comment: Does this really work? I tried to do something similar, but it acts as if the function called was `_.delay`ed instead of `_.debounce`d. Every time `$scope.parsePid` is called, won't it create a new debounced function and then call that new function instead of the old function instance? Debounce only works if you wrap your function once, and then call that instance multiple times. (Or maybe there's some IIFE magic happening that makes this work and I just completely missed the point.)

Comment: I believe there is a potential and significant problem with debounced functions that have arguments.  And that is, imagine calling in rapid succession:

`$scope.parsePid(1);`
`$scope.parsePid(2);`
`$scope.parsePid(1);`

Should the application parse only pid 1?  Or should it parse pid 1 and 2 in separate debounce queues?  This is a problem I recently discovered in code I created that was similar (debounce with arguments).

Comment: @ryanm that can indeed be a problem, but in some scenarios that doesn't matter much. I was working on a case where the debounce method is almost certainly guaranteed to be called with the same parameter in the tiny interval (250 ms) I defined for it, and if the user manages to invoke it from another part of the module with a different parameter, it's still not the end of the world.

Comment: @downhand Sure - sometimes it's not a problem, but if it is, there needs to be a plan.  (Though this problem was a while back, I ended up creating a version that had separate debounce calls based on the parameter called.)

Comment: @downhand I'm currently facing this same problem in updating records in tables. the function is possibly called several times with different parameters (think of a user checking boxes for each row) but a debounced function would ignore the later calls.

Comment: @coderatchet of course I don't know the size of your list, but in case you're using debounce here, ideally it would scan the whole list every time, like \_.pluck(\_.filter(rows, 'selected'), 'Id'). That's certainly an efficient and reliable method for lists of size 10-20.